# cant get data with json jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

trying to get data by Id of label here is the script;

```
 $(document).on('click', '.call', function () {
        var nId = $(this).data("id")
        GetText(nId);
    });

    function GetText(id) {
        var callid = id;
        alert(callid);
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: '@Url.Action("TextData","Home")',
            data: "{'callid':'" + callid+ "' }",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != null) {
                    $("#text").html(data.d);

                }
                else {

                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

        return false;

    }
```

and here is controller ;

```
public JsonResult TextData()
    {
        var model = Db.texttable.Select(s => new HomeModel.Content
            {
                text=s.text,
            });

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I can get Id but I cannot get text into the label called #text in success how can I fix and also do it with less code

here is my list ;

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.AyetContent)
  {
    <div><i class="fa fa-share"></i>@item.Baslik</div>
                                    @Html.Raw(item.Text)
    <div>
    @foreach (var itemDesc in Model.Ayetler.Where(o => o.Ayet == item.Id))
    {
    <div><span style="cursor:pointer;float:right;" class="call" data-id="@itemDesc.Id"><i class="fa fa-random"></i> @itemDesc.Baslik <br /></span></div><br />
     }
     </div>
     }
```

here is the part that should reach

```
  <div class="post">
  <label id="text"></label>
   </div>
```

I made this instead of upper jquery

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TextData", "Home")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#text").append(result);
                alert(result);
            }
```

now it returns [object Object][object Object]

Comment: Can you provide the html code?

Comment: 'd' is the property name?

Comment: Microsoft does this to protect you from a security exploit(data.d)

Comment: you can use data. Why are you trying with data.d. it's only for asp.net.

Comment: but data.d is only for asp.net not for as.net mvc.

Comment: oh didnt now that gonna delete d

Comment: but still doesnt work

Comment: what your getting in the data. did you check?

Comment: I dont see any error in the console only Id works

Comment: can you capture the ajax request in the developer tool of the Browser in the network tab. just what your getting in response

Comment: I only see Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: you are returning the model and assigning it to label. it's the json not a text?

Comment: in the model I pick text and return it with json so shouldnt it bring me the text and apply on the lable ?

Comment: I have changed the code litlte bit gonna edit

Comment: try $("#text").html(data.text); i think this will work

Comment: didnt work still same

Comment: try with $("#text").html(data.Text);

Comment: but also alert doesnt show text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
$("#text").append(result.text);
```

Also, you only need one record and an anonymous object:

```
Db.texttable.Select(s => new { text = s.text }).First();
```